# xslt max function to find maximum value

Tags: xslt

I am using the xslt max function to find the maximum of given sequence values.

xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"

```
<xsl:variable name="max" select="fn:max(2,4,1)"/>
```

Tired using xslt1.0,2.0. It's not working. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't tell us it doesn't work, tell us how it fails. If you told us that, we could probably tell you that the reason is that you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor. As it is, we can only guess that that's the explanation, based on the fact that so many people make the mistake of thinking that writing version="2.0" in their stylesheet will magically make their ancient XSLT processor understand XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

In XSLT 2.0, the expression:

```
max((2,4,1))
```

will return 4.

Note the inner parentheses that make the (single) argument a sequence. Without them, you would have 3 arguments - which is not a valid syntax for this function.

Comment: I've tried using max((2,4,1)) , not working . Checking to see if we have the support for 2.0 in the tool I'm using. Alternatively do we have any similar functions available in xslt 1.0 ?

Comment: No, in XSLT 1.0 you need to sort them and take the last (or the first). Please post a [mcve] if you can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Microsoft's XSLT engine (i.e. an [XslCompiledTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx)) you can use inline scripts to create a max function.

**XSLT**

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:monkey="urn:JohnLBevan/Xslt2.0/MonkeyPatch"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- \this is our call to the max function\ -->
    <xsl:variable name="max" select="monkey:max(2,4)"/>
    <!-- /this is our call to the max function/ -->

    <!-- match any xml file and stick our max value in the root element -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name='{name(.)}' namespace="{namespace-uri(.)>
            <xsl:value-of select="$max" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- \this is our max function definition\ -->
    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="monkey">
        <![CDATA[
```

```cs
        public static long max(long a, long b)
        {
            return a > b ? a: b;
        }
```

```xsl
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
    <!-- /this is our max function definition/ -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Example Call (PowerShell)**

```powershell
    $XsltFilename = '.\MyXslt.xsl'
    $Path = '.\MyData.xml'

    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Xml'
    $xslt = New-Object 'System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform'
    $settings = New-Object 'System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings'
    $settings.EnableScript = $true;
    $xslt.Load($XsltFilename, $settings, (New-Object 'System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver'))
    $xslt.Transform($Path, "$Path.out.xml")
```

**Example Call (C#)**

```csharp
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
public class XmlDemo 
{
    public static void TransformXml(string xsltFilename, string xmlFilename) 
    {
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = New XslCompiledTransform();
        XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
        settings.EnableScript = true;
        xslt.Load(xsltFilename, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
        xslt.Transform(xmlFilename, xmlFilename + ".out.xml")
    }
}
```

---

Sadly these scripts don't recognise IComparable or params, so the following options, whilst being more flexible / useful, are not valid:

**IComparable (invalid)**

```xsl
    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="monkey">
        <![CDATA[
```

```cs
        public static IComparable max(IComparable a, IComparable b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) >=0 ? a: b;
        }
```

```xsl
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
```

**Params (invalid)**

```xsl
    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="monkey">
        <msxsl:assembly name="System.Core" />
        <msxsl:using namespace="System.Linq" />
        <![CDATA[
```

```cs
        public static object max (params object[] args)
        {
            return args.Max(); //IEnumerable.Max from Linq
        }
```

```xsl
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
```